# asp.net mvc 4.6 access all route dictionary parameters and values from controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code

```
public class UserProfileController : Controller 
{
  public ActionResult Index(string manager="",string status="") 
  {
    var rvd = // Get route value dictionary for current call
    UserProfileService.GetEmployees(rvd);
    return View(vm);
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to pass a RouteValueDictionary to UserProfileService that includes key\values for manager and status.

e.g

If I made the following request,https://localhost:44301/UserProfile?manager=bill&status=active 
I would expect the route value dictionary to contain manager and status keys.

So far all I can find is RouteDate with key\values for "controller" and "action" but not action method parameter values "manager","active".

Comment: use Request.QueryString

Comment: I want to know all the parameters of the route including controller and action. Requert.QueryString only gives you the query parameters.

Comment: I would also like to know this, but at the moment it looks like accessing both collections (RouteData and QueryString) and checking both

Answer (score 0):

ended up creating and extension method to do the job.

```
public static IDictionary<string,string> MergeRouteQueryValues (this Controller c) {
  var d = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
    {"controller",c.ControllerName()},
    {"action",c.ActionName()}
  };
  foreach (string key in c.Request.QueryString.Keys) { 
    d.Add(key,c.Request.QueryString[key]);
  }
  return d;
}
```